# Ultralight C, Smartcardio and ACR122

Tags: nfc, smartcard-reader, acr122

I'm developing in a Java project with a PS/SC ACR122U with the library SmartCardIO. When I put a password and modified the page 0x2A, I am trying to read again the tag. Indeed, I know the protocol and I found here (http://www.eps.no/downloads/pdf/API_ACR128_v1.9.pdf) the APDU Command is:

```
FF 00 00 00 02 1A 00
```

But when I introduce that APDU I get an exception with message:

```
apdu must be at least 2 bytes long
```

However I'm using a tool called ACE122U Tool where I can send APDU Commands to the Tag and I can see how it answers me. So when I send the command before the tag doesn't answer.

I don't know how can I resolve it, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incredible, I posted the problem and looking again for a solution, I found the solution. Naturally, the APDU Command was wrong. The command is:

```
FF:00:00:00:04:D4:42:1A:00
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, Georgevik. Yes, you got the error as the response was too short from the card. Glad you got it solved...

Comment: Hi Georgevik,
Do you remember how you got 'D4:42' part of the above command?
 
I know that 'FF:00:00:00' is part of pseudo-APDU, '04' refers number of bytes, '1A:00' is APDU for authentication, but cannot figure out what 'D4:42' is and how is it calculated.

Comment: I understand that 'D4:42' is fixed.
Ie. 
`FF:00:00:00:04:D4:42:1A:00`
`FF:00:00:00:08:D4:42:11:22:33:44:55:66`

Comment: @yash The `D4:42` part comes from the PN532 NFC Controller chip specification. `D4` is the _frame identifier_. It is fixed for frames which go the way from the host controller to the PN532. `D5` is used for frames which go the other way (from the PN532 to the host controller). `42` is an initiator command (called `InCommunicateThru`) of the PN532. See its user manual: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/141520.pdf (p66).